# Is the Flutter SDK Version defined anywhere in code?

Tags: flutter, dart, codemagic, pubspec

I see that in the pubspec the Dart SDK version is [specified/constrained](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints) but is there anywhere to specify the Flutter SDK version? Maybe I'm missing something obvious but coming from other tech stacks like Java/Gradle I believe normally SDK versions are explicit?

What got me thinking about this is that I'm using Codemagic and have my Flutter version at "default" but I can't even tell what that is from their docs or their build logs.

[image]

Comment: It isn't specified in your `pubspec.yaml` by default, but you can add a flutter version constraint if you want. Look at the section titled "Flutter SDK constraints" in the link you posted.

Comment: interesting not sure how I missed that - any idea why this isn't standard practice? like they don't do it in the codelabs, flutterflow, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like it's easy to limit it like this - I just missed it in the [doc](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints).

If I say I need ^4.0.0 then I get a meaningful error:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ^4.0.0
```

> Running "flutter pub get" in XXXX... Resolving
> dependencies... The current Flutter SDK version is 3.7.1.
>
> Because XXXX requires Flutter SDK version >=4.0.0, version
> solving failed. pub get failed command:
> "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.10/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
> __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example" pub env: {   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.10/flutter",
> "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",   "PUB_CACHE":
> "/Users/DENNCH3/.pub-cache", } exit code: 1

Answer (score 0):

You can get that from your terminal just run `flutter --version`, this will print out your current flutter SDK and dart SDK versions.

```
flutter --version
```

the result should be similar to this

```
Flutter 3.7.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b06b8b2710 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
Engine • revision b24591ed32
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 • DevTools 2.20.1
```